# Exited with code: 1 Error with launchd

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, shell-script, launchd

I am trying to run a job with `launchd` which runs a shell script that creates a zip file I then backup.

I am receiving the error: `6/26/13 5:04:37.992 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[162]: (com.ian.evernote[18163]) Exited with code: 1`

Here is my `launchd plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ian.evernote</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/user/Dropbox/evernote.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo zip -r ~/Documents/evernote_backup /Users/user/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library
```

The shell script runs fine from the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute `sudo` inside the script. Who's going to enter the password? Why do you need this in the first place? It looks like you are operating inside your home folder where you should have all the permissions you want.

There are two solutions.

- You need elevated privileges

Make this job a launch daemon instead of an agent. Make sure you change the paths to absolute ones (`~` will expand to the executing users home directory, which is `/` for launch daemons).

- You're fine with standard privileges

Don't use `sudo`.

Also: As the script consists of a single line I'd suggest to drop the script and call `zip` directly:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/zip</string>
    <string>-r</string>
    <string>/Users/user/Documents/evernote_backup</string>
    <string>/Users/user/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I have `sudo` in the script because it doesn't zip without it. `zip I/O error: Permission denied
zip error: Could not create output file (/Users/user/Documents/evernote_backup.zip)` I tried your suggestion of calling it directly but now I get `exited with code 15` where do I find out what these codes mean? Is there a reason for the ending line of `<string>/usr/bin/zip</string>` ? I also set the privileges on the `.sh` file to `x` for everyone so I dont know why I needed `sudo` at all.

Comment: Got it to work had to make a folder just for the zip with write permission for everyone.

Comment: I removed the last `<string>/usr/bin/zip</string>` line in the array. The pleasures of copy&paste. As for the error codes: they are usually documented in the man pages. Try `man zip` and you'll find: 15: zip was unable to create a file to write to

Comment: Thanks. I turned on debugging for `launchd` and finally figured it out.